# Abstract Class bean definition for autowired field within jar

Tags: spring, javabeans, abstract, extend, autowired

I am having a problem with autowiring. Here is my project's situation:

I have a jar (let's call it **module.jar**). This jar contains an Interface (*IService*):

```
package com.module.service;

public interface IService {

    String create(Object data) throws Exception;
    String update(Object data);
}
```

an abstract class which implements the interface (*ServiceImpl*):

```
package com.module.service

public abstract class ServiceImpl implements IService {

    @Override
    public final String create(Object data) throws Exception {
        return update(data);
    }

    public abstract String update(Object data);
}
```

and a separate class which has an autowired *IService* field:

```
package com.module.service;

public class DoSomething {

    @Autowired
    IService service;

    public String doCreate(Object data) {
        return service.create(data);
    }
}
```

I have a project (let's call it **project**). This project contains **module.jar**,  and a class which extends the abstract *ServiceImpl* (we'll call it *ServiceImplExt*). *ServiceImplExt* is declared like so:

```
package com.project.service;

import com.module.service.ServiceImpl;

@Service
public class ServiceImplExt extends ServiceImpl {

    @Override
    public String update(Object data) {
        data.setFname("John");
        data.setLname("Doe");
        return data;
    }   
}
```

I have added the *ServiceImplExt*'s package to the component-scan of my spring xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.service" />

</beans>
```

After all of this, still when I start the server I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.demo.service.IService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 42 more
```

I cannot figure out what it is that I can be doing wrong. Any ideas?

---

Added the code, added xml to aide potential helpers

Comment: Can you show us your spring xml files or Java Config classes?

Comment: Ok, I have added the code from my projects

Comment: Why DoSomething is on com.module.service?? Is it declared as a bean on a XML file? That XML file is on module.jar or project.jar? What I want to know is when the spring container is initializing DoSomething class.

Comment: how are you configuring DoSomething, as an XML bean, component scan? could you post that config as well